# MATLAB - Meaning of guassian distribution data. (in Neural Network)

Tags: matlab, neural-network, data-science

I'm a newbie to MATLAB and now I'm trying to create a 2-d gaussian distribute data to train my neural network. I just found the code on the official document.

```
mu = [0 0];
Sigma = [.25 .3; .3 1];
x1 = -3:.2:3; x2 = -3:.2:3;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
```

I know "mu" is average of the data. Sigma is something related to 
Standard deviation. But I just don't get what is the idea of mesgrid and the interval(x1,x2). And the Geometric meaning of these code.

Also, can someone explain me why is guassian distribution so important in machine learning and data science? Cause all the course keep saying and saying this term.

Answer (score 0):

Meshgrid is a basic matlab function, that is in no way specifically related to neural networks or a gaussian distribution. Check [the documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of Matlab to find out more about it.

The gaussian distribution (also known as normal distribution) is important for datascience because it comes with several nice statistical properties. Unfortunately it is hard to describe them all in a compact way, and this would also not be a question about programming, but more about statistics.

Comment: I just don't get it why we need to give an interval to create a set of guassian distribution data

Comment: @Pwan If you are referring to the input of meshgrid, it does in fact not take an interval as input. Instead it takes 2 vectors. -- It appears that these vectors are points at which you later want to calculate the pdf.

Comment: ye. there are 2 vectors. but the data within it is between -3 to 3. what if i change it to -100 to 100. what is the key idea here? thanks

Comment: @Pwan Just try it, it should be fairly obvious what will happen if you look at the result.

Comment: I know that meshgrid is to take 2 1-d vectors and output 2 matrix. What I don't understand is what does it do to create gaussian distribute data, "mvnpdf". Is the purpose of meshgrid here to control how many data point to create on this distribution? what i mean above is that if i change it to -100 to 100. what does it affect to the guassian distribution data output. I try to plot it but it seems the same. If I want to create 100 data point what the strategy should i apply? thanks for your answer. I'm very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you provide seems confusing to you because you expect it to generate samples whereas it merely returns values of the Gaussian PDF (probability density function) for some given pairs of (x1,x2).
For example F = mvnpdf(a,b,mu, Sigma) returns the probability of x1=a and x2=b given that they follow a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean mu and covariance matrix Sigma.

Being in Stack Overflow, I am focusing on the Matlab aspect of your question: for generating 100 samples of a 2-D Gaussian you can use something like the following (taken from the Matlab help of randn function):

```
      mu = [1 2];
      Sigma = [1 .5; .5 2]; 
      R = chol(Sigma);
      z = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;
```

The array z = [x1,x2] contains the x1 and x2 vectors that you are looking for.

Some statistics textbook or wikipedia could convince you on why the above code indeed generates such samples. The last line of code is related to one of the nice properties of a Gaussian distribution (or any other elliptical distribution).